# When I drag a pix from Photos to the desktop, why doesn't it stay where I dropped it?

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app, ui

I'm using El Capitan and the Photos app.

I drag-and-drop a photo from Photos onto a visible spot on my desktop.

The problem is, the photo icon appears elsewhere on my desktop, so to do anything with it -- double click to open in another app -- I have to minimize my application to locate it wherever it end up on the desktop.

I feel like Mac OS X didn't used to do this, that it file icons appeared exactly where they were dropped.

Is there some setting I have to enable/disable to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Right click the desktop, check if you have a 'Sort By' [other than Snap to Grid] or 'Arrange By' option selected.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have some kind of auto arrange enabled. Right-click on the desktop and disable Sort By / Arrange By.